# Use the last row count in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

The following code allows me to repeat a formula from row 2 to all rows up to the last active row.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("C PUR TYPE")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("M2:M" & LastRow).formula = "=IFERROR(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A1932,$L$2:$L1932),"" 0,"",""""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A1932,$L$2:$L1932),"" 0,"",""""))-2),"" - "")"
End With
```

In this instance there are 1'932 active rows.

Is there a way that I can replace the cell reference :$A1932 and $L1932 in the formula to using the last row count as the row count will be different each time the report runs.

Thanks

Comment: You just use the `&` symbol to conctat the string of your formula with the `LastRow` variable.  So in your case it would be: `...Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A" & LastRow & ",$L$2:$L" & LastRow & "),...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `&` will allow you to concatenate the variable into the string:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("C PUR TYPE")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("M2:M" & LastRow).formula = "=IFERROR(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A" & LastRow & ",$L$2:$L" & LastRow & "),"" 0,"",""""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A" & LastRow & ",$L$2:$L" & LastRow & "),"" 0,"",""""))-2),"" - "")"
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me like you can use a variable similar to how you calculated `lastRow`.

Example (assuming you don't have any blanks in column A):

`dim LookupLastrow as long`

`LookupLastrow=range("A1").end(xldown).row`

then replace the 1932 references in your formula with " & lookuplastrow & ":

```
.Range("M2:M" & LastRow).formula = "=IFERROR(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A" & lookuplastrow & ",$L$2:$L" & lookuplastrow & "),"" 0,"",""""),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Lookup_concat(A2,$A$2:$A" & lookuplastrow & ",$L$2:$L" & lookuplastrow & "),"" 0,"",""""))-2),"" - "")"
```

Comment: `End(xlDown)` is NOT a good way to find the LastRow.  It will not work if the column (in your example "A") has blanks.